# VBA Reference object created in a form module

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created my own class called Organisation. In a pop out form that the user enters the details of the organisation, an instance of the Organisation class is instantiated.

e.g.

```
Public myOrg as COrganisation
Set myOrg = New COrganisation
```

The properties of the object were then set.

e.g.

```
myOrg.name = "General Corp"
myOrg.address1 = "1 Enterprise Ave"
```

That pop up form will then close. From the main form (where the pop up form comes from when a user selects a particular option) then I want to access the properties of the Organisation class. So I tried

```
myOrg.name
```

but received an error, 'Object Required'. 
Can I not access the object here even though I declared it as Public?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you declare the variable as public? In a standard module or in a form (class) module?

Comment: You need to use a standard module.